# pushViewController without navigationcontroller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview

I have a class that is of type `UITableViewController`.
This class has a member of type `UINavigationBar` that I use for adding in an edit button for the table view.

Using this method calling is invalid.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller];
```

How can I push a detail view onto the view after selecting a table row without wrapping my `UITableViewController` in a `UINavigationController`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't push a view controller onto a navigation controller if there is no navigation controller. If you are wanting to be pushing controllers and have it display the topmost controller and everything, just use a UINavigationController and be done with it.

You can push arbitrary [UINavigationItem](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html)s onto your UINavigationBar, and your bar's delegate will be notified when the user uses the back button so you can take appropriate action. See [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html) for more information.

Answer (score 38):

The closest alternative if you don't want to use navigation controller are modal view controllers.

```
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This will slide the controller into your screen from bottom, or if you change controller's `modalTransitionStyle` it can flip over or fade in.

To dismiss the controller just call:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 16):

I would wrap the UITableView inside a UINavigationController and just hide the UINavigationBar.

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

And then create a back button that pops the ViewController off the stack.

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

Answer (score 15):

What could also be done is to use a Navigation Controller as usual and then hide it.

To hide the Navigation Controller using storyboards: select it and uncheck "Show Navigation Bar" in the attribute inspector. Others might suggest to hide the navigation bar in each controller, but the problem with that is that it will appear for a millisecond and then disappear.

[image: Navigation Controller attributes tab]

Answer (score 1):

It's true that without a `UINavigationController` you can not push view controllers. You rather present view controllers modally via  `UIViewController.present(_ viewControllerToPresent:, animated:, completion:)`

But it's possible to create a custom segue to display the view controller as if it were a push (or any other animation you want), although it seems that using a `UINavigationController` just makes things easier.

Here are some related links to the documentation:

[UINavigationController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller)

[Customizing the Transition Animations](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CustomizingtheTransitionAnimations.html)

[Presenting a Modal View Controller](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621380-present)