# PushView on PresentViewController iOS

Tags: ios, presentmodalviewcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I want to `Push` my viewController on `PresentViewController`

When i click on button initially i am loading `PresentViewController`, here is my code.

```
- (IBAction)JoinClicked:(id)sender{

    JoinWithViewController *detail_view_controller = [[JoinWithViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"JoinWithViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:detail_view_controller
                                                      animated:YES
                                                    completion:NULL];

}
```

this works fine, but when i click on button which is there on `PresentViewController` on click i want to Push my view, but in does not pushes.

**Please help, Thanks in advance.**

Comment: :How you initialize the rootViewController in appDelegate please put your code.

Comment: There is nothing in `appDelegate` i am using stroyboard

Comment: You can also use CATransition to pudh your view with animation with duration.
Use <QuartzCore/CAAnimation.h> framework for that.

Comment: do u know any example for this ?

Comment: If even though you use storyBoard you need to do didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
self.viewController = [[viewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"viewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = nav; to push viewController

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014129/pushviewcontroller-without-navigationcontroller should adequately explain exactly a push.

Comment: @TamilKing: When i wrote your code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` there i am unable to see my Bottom `TabBar`

Comment: @Krunal:Are you using tab bar. OtherWise Wait I ll update my code you Create TabBar programaticaly. I ll update one sample code in my ans You refer that

Comment: But for some reason i have to use storyboard,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JoinWithViewController *detail_view_controller = [[JoinWithViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"JoinWithViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detail_view_controller animated:YES];
```

Try like this to push viewController. If you use TabBar do like this in **AppDelegate**. If you create TabBar Drag and drop means leave that. Create TabBar Programatically like below.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UITabBarController *tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];

    self.viewController = [[CalculatorViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CalculatorViewController" bundle:nil];
    UITabBarItem *tab_item1 = [[UITabBarItem alloc]init];
    //tab_item1.title = @"Calculator";
    tab_item1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Calculator.png"];
    [self.viewController setTabBarItem:tab_item1];
    UINavigationController *nav1 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];

    ShowPhoneViewController *phone = [[ShowPhoneViewController alloc]init];
    UITabBarItem *tab_item2 = [[UITabBarItem alloc]init];
    tab_item2.title = @"Latest Mobiles";
    tab_item2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Mobile.png"];
    [phone setTabBarItem:tab_item2];
    UINavigationController *nav2 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:phone];

    CurrencyConvertorViewController *currency = [[CurrencyConvertorViewController alloc]init];
    UITabBarItem *tab_item3 = [[UITabBarItem alloc]init];
    tab_item3.title = @"Units Convertor";
    tab_item3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Dollar.png"];
    [currency setTabBarItem:tab_item3];
    UINavigationController *nav3 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:currency];

    SettingsPageViewController *setting = [[SettingsPageViewController alloc]init];
    UITabBarItem *tab_item4 = [[UITabBarItem alloc]init];
    tab_item4.title = @"Settings";
    tab_item4.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Settings.png"];
    [setting setTabBarItem:tab_item4];
    UINavigationController *nav4 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:setting];


    tabController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nav1, nav2, nav3, nav4, nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = tabController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

I hope you got now

Comment: @Krunal:You got output as you want?

Answer (score 1):

**pushviewcontroller** is the feature of **UINavigationController** where you can push one viewcontroller on another vierw controller. Here you are using a single viewcontroller as a rootviewcontroller so either you must change your **rootviewcontroller** to **UINavigationcontroller** or you can use "**addSubview method**" to add new viewController on the current viewcontroller.

but the better option is to add **uinavigationcontroller** as a **rootviewcontroller**.

> AppDelegate.m
>
> -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
>
> ```
>      FirstViewController *first = [[FirstViewController alloc]
>                                  initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
>      UINavigationController *navController =[[UINavigationController alloc] 
>                                             initWithRootViewController:first];
>      [self.window setRootViewController:navController];
> ```
>
> }

Now when as you want to switch from FirstViewController to SecondViewController on button clicked than you have to use pushviewcontroller

> ***FirstViewController.h***
>
> ```
> -(void) nextBtnPressed {
>     SecondViewController *second = [[SecondViewController alloc]  initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
>      [self.navigationController pushViewController:second animated:TRUE];
>  }
> ```

Comment: When i wrote your code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` there i am unable to see my Bottom `TabBar`

Comment: 1. In Appdelegte.m you use to add navigation controller as rootviewcontroller(here FirstViewController is rootViewController of UINavigationController).
 2. (when you are not using Storyboard)Now Suppose on next button pressed, you want switch from FirstViewController to SecondViewController than you must call nextBtnPressed method.